# How to declare a variable that can be accessed by all the classes in android?

Tags: android, variables, radio-button

I'm a new to android please help me with the following.

I'm having an integer value which stores the id of a checked radiobutton. I need to access this value throughout the various classes of my app for a validation purpose.

Please let me know how to declare and access this variable from all the classes.

Thank you.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: First of all, the ID of the checkbox is storen in the R.java file, so you can access it from anywhere (no need to store it). Then in every activity, you can just: `checkBox.isChecked()` to see if it's checked, you don't have to store anything anywhere, just declare the checkBox like `Checkbox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById (R.id.checkbox1);` and use the function from above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use:

MainActivity.class

```
Public static int myId;
```

In other Activities.

```
int otherId=MainActivity.myId;
```

Comment: hard dependency on MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

following singleton pattern is the only way to do this.in java/android if u create a instance for a class every time it create a new object.what you should do is

```
1.create a model class and  make its as singleton 
2.try to access the modelclass from every class



public class CommonModelClass 
{
    private static CommonModelClass singletonObject;
    /** A private Constructor prevents any other class from instantiating. */

    private CommonModelClass() 
    {
        //   Optional Code
    }
    public static synchronized CommonModelClass getSingletonObject() 
    {
        if (singletonObject == null) 
        {
            singletonObject = new CommonModelClass();
        }
        return singletonObject;
    }


    /**
     * used to clear CommonModelClass(SingletonClass) Memory
     */ 
     public void clear()  
      {  
         singletonObject = null;  
      }


    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException 
    {
        throw new CloneNotSupportedException();
    }

    //getters and setters starts from here.it is used to set and get a value

    public String getcheckBox()
    {
        return checkBox;
    }

    public void setcheckBox(String checkBox)
    {
        this.checkBox = checkBox;
    }   

}
```

accessing the model class values from other class
commonModelClass = CommonModelClass.getSingletonObject();

commonModelClass.getcheckBox(); 
http://javapapers.com/design-patterns/singleton-pattern/

Comment: Checkbox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById (R.id.checkbox1); u can store this checkBox instance in sigleton and access through out the app

Comment: Thank you Ruban, I tried accessing by declaring the integer as public static int it works well. But I'm unaware of the technique you specified. Hence gonna try that too, thank you.

Comment: using static is also a good thing.but implementing singleton pattern first makes u bit difficult to implement.but if u once use it then u will find more advantage of using it

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your integer variable as `static` and access in any class.Like this

```
    class A{

       static int a;
        }
```

You can access in another class like this.

```
   class B{

    int b = A.a; 
    }
```